# GET REST error 415

Tags: java, rest

I am getting the following error message when trying to execute a GET REST command:

"returned a response status of 415 Unsupported Media Type"

This is the code:

```
<code> whenGetPatternByGroupName() {
        Client client = Client.create(new DefaultClientConfig());

        URI uri = UriBuilder.fromUri("http://bla:7979/bla/rest/pattern/").build();
        WebResource service = client.resource(uri);

        List <PatternList> patternList = new ArrayList<PatternList>();
        patternList = service.path("getAll").type(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML).get(patternList.getClass());

        assertThat(patternList.size(), greaterThan(0));
     }
</code>

<code> @GET
    @Path("getAll")
    @Consumes({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
    public List<PatternList> getAllPatterns() { 
        ArrayList<PatternList> list = new ArrayList<PatternList>();

        // put group names here
        String[] groups = new String[] {"Group 1"};

        for (String groupName : groups) {

            List<String> patterns = patternPersistenceService.getListByGroupName(groupName);

            PatternList patternList = new PatternList();
            patternList.setGroupName(groupName);
            patternList.setPatterns(patterns);

            list.add(patternList); 
        }
        return list;
    }
</code>
```

Does anyone have any ideas what could be causing this??

Thanks,

Comment: It might be help to you.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4308672/is-restlet-returning-415-unsupported-media-type-when-it-should-return-400-bad-re.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting the media type for a GET request and using `@Consumes` in the handler seems strange since a GET request does not have a body. Don't you mean to use the `accept` method in the client and `@Produces` on the server side?

Comment: Ok i tried changing to <code>@Produces</code> and accept but get the following now: SEVERE: A message body reader for Java class java.util.ArrayList, and Java type class java.util.ArrayList, and MIME media type application/json was not found

Comment: Could you also try passing `List.class` instead of `patternList.getClass()`?

Comment: Seems to be a bit more complicated with generics, try `new GenericType<List<PatternList>>` as described at http://jersey.576304.n2.nabble.com/How-can-I-parse-a-java-util-List-lt-gt-Is-it-supported-by-the-Jersey-client-td2300852.html

Comment: Thanks that worked with the GenericType used! Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

You have mixed the `MediaType` (and your methods does not consume anything at all ...):

- Client: `MediaType.APPLICATION_XML`
- Rest: `MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON`

Comment: Ok, I tried setting both of them to JSON and now get the following:  SEVERE: A message body reader for Java class java.util.ArrayList, and Java type class java.util.ArrayList, and MIME media type application/xml was not found