# How to send a Http post request in objective c?

Tags: objective-c, ios, youtube-api, asihttprequest

I am trying to send a post request to youtube to add a video to favorite list. The API document is [here](https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_favorites#Adding_a_favorite_video)

and here is my source code:

```
- (void) addVideoToFavoriteWithID:(NSString *)strVideoID{
    NSString* strConnection = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",CONNECTION_YOUTUBE, CONNECTION_ADD_VIDEO_TO_FAVORITE];
    AppDelegate* delegate =    (AppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    ASIFormDataRequest *formData = [[ASIFormDataRequest alloc]initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:strConnection]];
    [formData setRequestMethod:@"POST"];
    [formData setPostValue:@"2" forKey:@"GData-Version"];
    [formData setPostValue:@"application/atom+xml" forKey:@"Content-Type"];
    [formData setPostValue:YOUTUBE_DEVELOPER_KEY    forKey:@"X-GData-Key"];
    [formData setPostValue:[[delegate userInfo   ]accessTokenYoutube]  forKey:@"Authorization"];

    NSString *body = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?><entry xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom'><id>%@</id></entry>",strVideoID];
    [formData setPostValue:body forKey:@"body"  ];

    [formData setDelegate:self];
    [formData setDidFinishSelector:@selector(didAddVideoToFavoriteFinish:)];
    [formData setDidFailSelector:@selector(didAddVideoToFavoriteFail:)];\
    [formData setDidReceiveDataSelector:@selector(didAddVideoToFavoriteSelect:)];
    [formData startAsynchronous];

    [formData release];
}
```

In the method `didAddVideoToFavoriteFinish`, I receive the message:

> HTTP/1.1 415 Unsupported Media Type

Please tell me what is my mistake here is. I am a new to objective C and I am really confused with this.

Comment: `[415 Unsupported Media Type] If the client sends a document that’s got the right media type but the wrong format (such as an XML document written in the wrong vocabulary), a better response is the more generic 400 (“Bad Request”)`  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4308672/is-restlet-returning-415-unsupported-media-type-when-it-should-return-400-bad-re

Answer (score 2):

Your POST request is a form data request, which is usually used post the data of an HTML form. It uses a special encoding for data. That's not what the YouTube API expects. It expects a simple POST request with an XML document.

Instead of the `ASIFormDataRequest` class, you should use the `ASIHTTPRequest` class. Your code should more or less look like this:

```
ASIHTTPRequest *request = [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:strConnection]];
[request setRequestMethod:@"POST"];
[request setPostValue:@"2" forKey:@"GData-Version"];
[request setPostValue:@"application/atom+xml" forKey:@"Content-Type"];
[request setPostValue:YOUTUBE_DEVELOPER_KEY    forKey:@"X-GData-Key"];
[request setPostValue:[[delegate userInfo   ]accessTokenYoutube]  forKey:@"Authorization"];

NSString *body = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?><entry xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom'><id>%@</id></entry>",strVideoID];
[request appendPostData:[body dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

[request setDelegate:self];
[request setDidFinishSelector:@selector(didAddVideoToFavoriteFinish:)];
[request setDidFailSelector:@selector(didAddVideoToFavoriteFail:)];\
[request setDidReceiveDataSelector:@selector(didAddVideoToFavoriteSelect:)];
[request startAsynchronous];

[request release];
```

Comment: do we have a setPostValue method in ASIHTTPRequest?
How this is worked for u?
@Codo

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can check about [this Objective-C API set](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-objectivec-client/) provided by Google. Write all the REST things could be painful.

Comment: I don't understand you answer, Onevcat. Could you please give me more details?

Comment: Google has already written (or generated) a lot of API in Objective-C, which can be found in the link above. In these APIs, almost all parts  network affairs are implemented for you, and you can just apply something like username or list name for your situation, and call a simple method to finish your job. That means you can get rid of the painful post/get/delete and write the request by your self.

You can check these OC APIs of Youtube in detail by this [link](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-objectivec-client/source/browse/#svn%2Ftrunk%2FSource%2FServices%2FYouTube%2FGenerated).

Comment: What i think onevcat is trying to say is to use a wrapper to construct your calls. Building the request, adding all headers, etc could be costly as time and code. You'd better check out the library Google provides in this regard. http://code.google.com/p/gdata-objectivec-client/
Edit: looks like onevcat explained himself already :)

Comment: Or if you want to implement the request by yourself, you can try some network frameworks, such as [AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking) or [MKNetworkKit](https://github.com/MugunthKumar/MKNetworkKit). I guess you will not want to use the Apple's network SDK, which is really hard to use.

Comment: Yes, you're right. For some special reasons, my team is implement request by ourself. The framework We are using is: ASIHTTPRequest